# How do I delete a row using two different column values sqlite

Tags: sqlite

What I'm trying to do is delete 1 row from this table using steam_id and the highest unique_id with said steam_id.

[picture of table](https://prnt.sc/gtk0j6)

In this picture, the first two entries have the same steam_id (intentional), what I'm trying to do is remove entry 2 based on the fact that its unique_id is higher than entry 1 however I do not want entry 1 removed.

This is currently what I have:

```
    "DELETE FROM hwarns WHERE steam_id = '76561198277645499'"
```

I just don't know what else I need to add, I tried adding a MAX clause however that failed and I have no clue what exactly to look up to find answers

NOTE: THIS IS FOR THE GAME 'Garry's Mod'

(sorry for bad explanation)

Answer (score 1):

DELETE FROM hwarns WHERE unique_id= (select max(unique_id) from hwarns where steam_id = '76561198277645499')